# How to convert PNG to pdf and center the image?

Tags: imagemagick

I'm using Magick's convert tool to convert and combine all my images into PDF.

`magick convert *.png -page a4 out.pdf`

The resolution of the images are `1079 x 1397`

The images in the generated PDF file are off-centered. There's some white space on the top of each page.

Here's a screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/69oHM.png

I don't want to "fill" the entire page with my image. I want to simply "fit" the image the way it has in the screenshot above, BUT be centered (have equal whitespace on the top and bottom)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can center with -page in ImageMagick 7 unless you do inline computations using the actual desired A4 size in pixels (592x842) via distort and its viewport setting. See page sizes in pixels at https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#page

In ImageMagick 7, you should use magick and not magick convert. The latter will emulate ImageMagick 6. However there is a bug currently in ImageMagick 7. The following command works fine with convert in ImageMagick 6, but fails with magick in ImageMagick 7. But it works fine with magick convert in ImageMagick 7.

```
magick convert *.jpg -virtual-pixel white -set option:distort:viewport "592x842-%[fx:(592-u[t].w)/2]-%[fx:(842-u[t].h)/2]" -distort SRT 0 +repage result.pdf
```

Here is a simple example:

Input Images:

[image]

[image]

```
magick convert lena.jpg barn.jpg -virtual-pixel white -set option:distort:viewport "592x842-%[fx:(592-u[t].w)/2]-%[fx:(842-u[t].h)/2]" -distort SRT 0 +repage result.pdf
```

[Result:](https://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/set_bug/result.pdf)